# Javascript Sort UUID

Tags: javascript, sorting, timestamp, uuid

I came across a scenario where I have array of UUID. I want to convert array of UUID to timestamp, sort it in descending order and convert it back to UUID *eg.* latest timestamp on top.

I am not able to proceed as I am not aware how to convert UUID to timestamp and sort it. Please Help.

```js
// Sort below UUID in desc order by converting them to timestamp

var arr = ['b35086d0-7de3-11ec-aa3a-f3f0af78e321',
'668a6d50-7dea-11ec-aa3a-f3f0af78e321',
'ca189d60-e730-11ec-9306-eb4991e07dcc',
'e944ab30-e734-11ec-8434-f5c328ae6aaa'];
```

**example:**

**Note:** Below Data is just presentation of manually converted UUID to timestamp

b35086d0-7de3-11ec-aa3a-f3f0af78e321 => Tuesday, January 25, 2022 at 1:35:46 PM

668a6d50-7dea-11ec-aa3a-f3f0af78e321 => Tuesday, January 25, 2022 at 2:23:43 PM

ca189d60-e730-11ec-9306-eb4991e07dcc => Wednesday, June 8, 2022 at 1:42:07 PM

e944ab30-e734-11ec-8434-f5c328ae6aaa => Wednesday, June 8, 2022 at 2:11:37 PM

**Output I need is UUID in Descending order Latest timestamp on top**

668a6d50-7dea-11ec-aa3a-f3f0af78e321

b35086d0-7de3-11ec-aa3a-f3f0af78e321

e944ab30-e734-11ec-8434-f5c328ae6aaa

ca189d60-e730-11ec-9306-eb4991e07dcc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I want to convert array of UUID to timestamp, sort it in descending order and convert it back to UUID eg. latest timestamp on top